# Excel VBA - Sort data into groups and insert headers

Tags: vba, excel

I'm hoping someone out there can help me with this one!

I have a section of my worksheet (say A10:D100) in which a user inputs data.

The end cell will always contain a group name/label (say "Tools", or "Spades", or **anything**) and the macro needs to sort all the data by these groups in alphabetical order, then insert a row above the group and add a header. The header will equal the group name in the end cell of the row below.

So something like this:

```
    A    B    C    D
(data)(data)(data)Tools
(data)(data)(data)Spades
(data)(data)(data)Boots
(data)(data)(data)Spades
(data)(data)(data)Tools
(data)(data)(data)Boots
(data)(data)(data)Boots
(data)(data)(data)PPE
etc.
```

To this:

```
    A    B    C    D
(data)(data)(data)Boots
(data)(data)(data)Boots
(data)(data)(data)Boots
(data)(data)(data)PPE
(data)(data)(data)Spades
(data)(data)(data)Spades
(data)(data)(data)Tools
(data)(data)(data)Tools
etc.
```

Then to something like this:

```
    A    B    C    D
Boots
(data)(data)(data)Boots
(data)(data)(data)Boots
(data)(data)(data)Boots    
PPE
(data)(data)(data)PPE
Spades
(data)(data)(data)Spades
(data)(data)(data)Spades
Tools
(data)(data)(data)Tools
(data)(data)(data)Tools
etc.
```

I found [this](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/453830-visual-basic-applications-insert-rows-between-groups-add-group-header-delete-repeating-values-below-header.html) and tried to adapt it but I got an error saying that 'This command requires Column Labels'.. am a bit out of my depth here!

Appreciate any help

---

### Code edited so in alphabetical order. Sorry :)

Comment: Did you try to insert a row of column labels to work around that error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't understand why the final solution is not sorted in alphabetical order, guess you need this.
I did not read the link, just tryed to code something for what you need:

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim i, n, values As Integer

n = 9 'last row, change it to your last row

With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

.Range("A1:D" & n).Select
Selection.Sort key1:=Range("D1:D" & n), _
    order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo

'count how much different values are in column D that are the numbers of
'rown i'm going to add
values = 1
For i = 2 To n
    If .Cells(i, 4) <> .Cells(i - 1, 4) Then
    values = values + 1
    End If
Next

'do the trik for the first row
.Rows(1).Insert
.Cells(2, 4).Copy Destination:=.Cells(1, 1)

'for the others (start from the third row because the first is already
'been inserted and filled and the second contains in col. D what it's been
'copyed in row 1
For i = 3 To (n + values) Step 1
    If .Cells(i, 4) <> .Cells(i - 1, 4) Then
    .Rows(i).Insert
    .Cells(i + 1, 4).Copy Destination:=.Cells(i, 1)
    i = i + 1
    End If
Next
End With
End Sub
```

Hope it's what you are looking for.

Ettore

Comment: Wow. I am impressed :) - simple bit of code but works beautifully! Thanks very much. Do you know why it inserts a row above the selection too? Doesn't matter very much but I wonder if it can be fixed..

Comment: You're welcome.  Don't understand your problem, when i try the code it inserts a row only where needed for make the "header" you are looking for. The data are supposed to be from A1 to D(row_you_specify_in_the_code)